# Merge 3 pandas based on key columns

Tags: python, pandas

I am new to pandas I have 3 CSV files extracted from a MySql database and stored in pandas dataframes. I have generated a sequential id for all the 3 files they look like this:

```
df1
id1 key_column1 name1
 1   567       qqq
 2   898       rrr
 3   345       bbb

df2
id2 key_column2 name2
 4   967       qqqq
 5   998       rrrr
 6   945       bbbb

df3
id3 key_column1 key_column2
 7   345       967     
 8   567       945
```

df1 and df2 represent 2 tables their original key_columns are key_column1 and key_column2, respectively. df3 containing the mapping from both df1 and df2 based on their key_columns. Now the df3 must do the mapping based on the generated sequential id it must look like this

```
 df3
  id3 id1  id2 key_column1 key_column2
   7   3    4     345       967     
   8   1    6     567       945
```

I have tried the merge initially of one columns but I have got none values.

```
df=pd.merge(df1,df3,left_on=df1['key_column1'],right_on=df3['key_column1'],how='inner')
```

Comment: please show us what you have tried so far. thanks.

Comment: df= pd.merge(df1,df3,left_on=df1['key_column1'],right_on=df3['key_column1'],how='inner')

Comment: Based on the result, your code is not showing none values.  You just need to drop some columns you don't want and rename it.  Please add more examples wherein you get None values

Answer (score 1):

You could create a dictionary from the columns in `df3` and use it to `map` the values in `key_column1`:

```
map_ = dict(zip(df3.key_column1, df3.key_column2))
key_df1 = df1.key_column1.map(map_).fillna(0)
```

And then [`merge`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) both dataframes having now the same keys:

```
(df1.merge(df2, left_on= key_df1, right_on='key_column2')
    .drop(['name1', 'name2'], 1))

    id1  key_column1  id2  key_column2
0    1          567    6          945
1    3          345    4          967
```

Answer (score 1):

We can use [`DataFrame.merge`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) twice to combine the three dataframes together. After that we use [`DataFrame.iloc`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html) to remove the columns we dont need.

```
df_all = df3.merge(df2, on='key_column2', suffixes=['', '_2'])\
            .merge(df1, on='key_column1', suffixes=['', '_1'])\
            .iloc[:, :-4]

print(df_all)
   id3  id1  id2  key_column1  key_column2
0    7    3    4          345          967
1    8    1    6          567          945
```

Comment: Thanks! how it can work without the columns name (without the header)

Comment: This is a pandas dataframe. All columns are named, if you want the underlying numpy arrays, simply use the `df.values` method @K.soula

Answer (score 1):

This seems like it works for me.

```
df3.merge(df1,how='left',on='key_column1').merge(df2,how='left',on='key_column2')

   id3  key_column1  key_column2  id1 name1  id2 name2
0    7          345          967    3   bbb    4  qqqq
1    8          567          945    1   qqq    6  bbbb
```

Comment: Note this is just merging.  You can remove columns post merge easily enough.